# The forms of $f,g \in k[x,y]$ such that $k[f,g,x]=k[x,y]$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, automorphism-group

Let $f=f(x,y), g=g(x,y) \in k[x,y]$ be two non-constant polynomials in two variables over a field of characteristic zero $k$.

Assume that $k[f,g,x]=k[x,y]$ and that $Jac(f,g):=f_xg_y-f_yg_x \in k[x,y]-k$ (namely, $f$ and $g$ are algebraically independent over $k$, but are not a Jacobian pair, where a Jacobian pair is a pair of polynomials having a Jacobian in $k^*$).
For example: $f=xy$ and $g=y$ (here, $Jac(f,g):=f_xg_y-f_yg_x=y1-x0=y$).

> Can one find a description for all such pairs of polynomials?

A partial answer is: $(f,g)=(f,y)$ with $f_x \in k[x,y]-k$; indeed,
$k[f,g,x]=k[f,y,x]=k[x,y]$ and $Jac(f,g)=f_x1-f_y0=f_x$.

**Remark:** If we replace the assumption that $Jac(f,g) \in k[x,y]-k$ by the assumption that $Jac(f,g) \in k^*$, then the answer is as follows: By [Formanek's theorem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01210711),  $k[f,g,x]=k[x,y]$ and $Jac(f,g) \in k^*$ imply that $k[f,g]=k[x,y]$. Then, $(x,y) \mapsto (f,g)$ defines an automorphism of $k[x,y]$ and it is well-known that an automorphism of $k[x,y]$ is [a products of affine and triangular automorphisms](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408077). (Another description: The group of automorphisms of $k[x,y]$ is a certain free amalgamated group).

Thank you very much!